# Inverse Laplace transform help- inverse heat conduction

Tags: laplace-transform, heat-equation

I've been stuck on an inverse Laplace transform for my research. Would be greatly appreciative of any help solving the inverse Laplace transform of

$$ 
\overline{T}=\frac{2}{k_{1}} \frac{1}{s} \left(\alpha_{1} / s\right)^{1 / 2}\left(\frac{1}{(1+\sigma) \exp \left\lbrace a\left(s / \alpha_{1}\right)^{1 / 2}\right\rbrace-(1-\sigma) \exp \left\lbrace-a\left(s / \alpha_{1}\right)^{1 / 2}\right\rbrace}\right)
 $$

$\alpha_1$, $a$, $k$, $\sigma$ are all constants.

To put this into context I've got a thin layer of insulating material on the surface of a thermocouple. Based on a measured temperature I need to determine the surface heat flux. The equation is Eq. 4 of doi: 10.1016/0017-9310(87)90045-7 if this has anyone interested

Edit: Additional information from here on.
This solution has been presented in another paper (doi: 10.1115/1.2752188) as 
$$
T_2(t) = \frac{2\left[1+\left( \frac{1-\sigma}{1+\sigma} \right)\right]\sqrt{\alpha_1}}{k_1} \left\lbrace \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}} \exp\left({\frac{a^2}{-4\alpha_1 t}}\right) - \left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}}\right) \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{4\sqrt{\alpha_1} \sqrt{t}}\right)  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1-\sigma}{1+\sigma} \right)^n \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}} \exp{\left(\frac{-k_a^2}{4t}\right)} - \frac{k_a}{2} \mathrm{erfc}\left( \frac{k_a}{2\sqrt{t}} \right)   \right)   \right\rbrace
$$ 
where $k_a = \frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$.
However, when I use this equation to process my experimental data the match is poor, especially for small $t$. If I change to $k_a = \frac{(2n+0)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$ the heat flux profile is perfect.

Because the experimental data matches the $k_a = \frac{(2n+0)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$ model I'm convinced it is correct, not $k_a = \frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$ (sample figure link at bottom of post). This is true for tests using square and Gaussian temporal profile heat flux. I've been stuck for over a year on/off on this problem and my thesis submission is coming up, and I'd like to get the work submitted to a journal before then. I'm looking for someone to tell me that my modification is valid, or for someone to call me an idiot if that's the case.

Variables: $\sigma$ is positive and greater than 1, in my actual case the value is about 4. $\alpha_1$ is positive (about $118\times 10^{-9}$), $a$ is positive (about $20\times 10^{-6}$), and $0\leq t \leq 1.5$ seconds.

[Sample result of the two models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMcoL.png)
Black- irradiance applied, red- heat flux from an experimental calibration, blue uses $k_a = \frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$, green uses $k_a = \frac{(2n+0)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$. The amplitude differences are because the apsorptivity of the material has to be determined which I am doing using results from the experimental (red) and analytical model (green or blue).

Note- more than happy to give credit on any publication that arises (currently with the unmodified model because we can justify using it)

Comment: Do we know if $\sigma$ is smaller or larger than 1?

Comment: @Mattos - I believe so, updated post to show what has been presented as a solution before, but it's poor at small $t$. Added my "correction" for what I think the solution is.

Comment: Does the model with $2n+1$ fit your data if you replace $\sigma$ with $1/\sigma$? If so I think I know what's going on here.

Comment: @eyeballfrog sorry, $\sigma > 1$ (early morning error) . No, does not fit model if changed to $1/\sigma$, but I've just found with some tweaking that the $k_a = 2n+1$ model shape is improved when $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$, but the result seems to be out by a factor of $\pi$

Comment: I have not looked into the paper, but just from glancing at $\overline{T}$ with kernel ${\rm e}^{st}$ you can transform the integrand with substitution $v=\sqrt{s}$ into a holomorph one. The new contour is a hyperbola with angle ${\rm e}^{\pm i\pi/4}$ at the asymptotics. Probably the denominator can then be converted using the geometric series and the integrals are elementary (error function). Since the integrand is holomorph the contour doesn't matter and you can evalute at $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} R{\rm e}^{\pm i\pi/4}$. Have you tried that?

Comment: But as far as I see it you are less worried about the way how to arrive at the result, but to the specific values the constants take, right?

Comment: @Diger Unfortunately my maths ability isn't high enough to solve (or even follow your suggestion). Not worried about the constants because I have those, but the solution to the inverse laplacian I suspect is incorrect

Comment: Could you provide some info about where your model comes from? I see that the Laplace transform you would like solved is indeed eqn. 4 from the 1st paper with $\alpha_2\rightarrow\infty$ but I do not understand how that relates to the other paper. Can you describe your experimental apparatus and your idealization of it and how it relates to the two papers?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I'll do my best to describe textually. I'd like Eq.4 of the 1st paper solved at $x=a$, so that's why the numerator I've written here is 1. I've changed nomenclature to match the papers, but the equation appears between Fig 10 and Fig 11 of the 2nd paper. What I have is a microsecond response time thermocouple behind a thin (about 15$\mu$m) layer of teflon. This resembles Fig7 of the 2nd paper, without the gauge at x=0. Calibrating the gauge using a step input heat flux. For this I need a basis function for T to pair with the step in q

Comment: @sleepy_panda: Maybe it is a bit more complicated, but essentially you want to integrate after $v=\sqrt{s}$ the expression $$\int \frac{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}}{v^2} \, {\rm e}^{tv^2-\frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}} \, v} \, {\rm d}v \, .$$  Without the $\frac{1}{s}$ the $\frac{1}{v^2}$ would not be there and you'd have a simple error function and exponential. But the constant $k_a=\frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$ is manifest already from this integral.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this Laplace transform factor $(1+\sigma)\exp(\sqrt{\frac{s}{\alpha_1}})$ and expand into a geometric series:

$$\bar{T}(s)=\frac{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}}{k_1(1+\sigma)}s^{-3/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1-\sigma}{1+\sigma}\Big)^n\exp\Big(-(2n+1)a\sqrt{\frac{s}{\alpha_1}}\Big)$$

And Mathematica returns for the ILT:

$$F(s)=s^{-3/2}e^{-a\sqrt{s}}\rightarrow f(t)= 2 e^{-a^2/4 t}\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi}} - a~\textrm{erfc}(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}})]$$

and substituting $k_s=\frac{a(2n+1)}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}}$, we get

$$T(t)=\frac{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}}{k_1(1+\sigma)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1-\sigma}{1+\sigma}\Big)^n[2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}\exp(-\frac{k_s^2}{4t})-k_s~\textrm{erfc}(\frac{k_s}{2\sqrt{t}})]$$

which is exactly the proposed solution, modulo elementary algebra.

EDIT: Calculating $I(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}e^{-a\sqrt{s}}e^{st}dt$.

Using the closed contour C that connects the lines $Re(z)=\sigma$,the circle in the infinite left half plane and a keyhole contour around the essential singularity at $s=0$ we obtain:

$$0=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C e^{-a\sqrt{z}}e^{zt}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ia\sqrt{r}-rt}dr-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ia\sqrt{r}-rt}dr+\int\limits_{z=Re^{i\theta}, \frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}}dze^{-a\sqrt{z}}e^{zt}-\int\limits_{z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}, -\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi }dze^{-a\sqrt{z}}e^{zt}+\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}e^{-a\sqrt{s}}e^{st}dt)$$.

Taking the limits $R\rightarrow\infty, \epsilon\rightarrow 0$ we obtain that

$$I(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(a\sqrt{r})}e^{-rt}dt=-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(ax)e^{-x^2 t}=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\pi}t^{3/2}}e^{-a^2/4t}$$

The calculation is similar for other powers of z in the denominator, but is more subtle potentially because of the worsening singularity at z=0. However, in the present case one can obtain the desired formula by integrating twice, once in t and once in a and applying appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: Actually wolframalpha didn't find a solution, how long did Mathematica calculate?

Comment: 0.4 secs, for free edition of wolfram alpha the input has to be grossly oversimplified and no free parameters. Do you need a derivation of this Laplace transform?

Comment: I'd be only interested in how to manually calculate $$I(t)=\int \frac{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}}{v^2} \, {\rm e}^{tv^2-\frac{(2n+1)a}{\sqrt{\alpha_1}} \, v} \, {\rm d}v \, .$$ I tried a couple of partial integrations, but that lead nowhere. $I'(t)$ can be simply calculated, but else I dunno.

Comment: Cheers, you're all legends. Even if you didn't tell me what I wanted to hear!

Comment: @Diger You need to use complex analysis or differentiation under the integral sign to compute this integral

Comment: @sleepy_panda research is hard for me too, glad to be of help!

Comment: @Diger edited with a similar calculation, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that trivial calculation ;). But I managed differently. The above integral $I(t)$ in my comment divided by $2\pi i$ can be simply integrated when deriving with respect to $t$, and then evaluated at $v=\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} R{\rm e}^{\pm i\pi/4}$ with the obtained antiderivative. The result is simply after $v$ has been eliminated $$I'(t)=\sqrt{4\alpha_1} \, \frac{{\rm e}^{-\frac{k_a^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$$ which can be integrated in $t$ and becomes $$\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha_1 t}{\pi}}\,{\rm e}^{-\frac{k_a^2}{4t}} + \sqrt{\alpha_1} k_a {\rm erf}\left(\frac{k_a}{\sqrt{4t}}\right)$$

Comment: The contours are not on the real axis, so you can't pretend they are and integrate like nothing happens if you want to be rigorous but you got it right so :)

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to do this through a slightly different route.

First let's get rid of those constants using the identity $F(s/\nu)/\nu = \mathcal{L}[f(\nu t)]$. Then $T_2(t) = f(\nu t)$, where $f$ satisfies
$$
\mathcal{L}[f](s) = \frac{2a}{k_1}\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(\sigma+1)e^\sqrt{s}+(\sigma-1)e^{-\sqrt{s}}},
$$
which now at least only has one parameter to worry about in the transform. Unfortunately, now we have to actually do it. Using the contour $(\alpha+iu)^2$ for the inverse Laplace transform and playing around with the resulting integral a bit, I managed to come up with
$$
f'(t) = \frac{a\sigma}{\pi k_1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-tu^2}\cos(u)}{1+(\sigma^2-1)\cos(u)^2}du.
$$
Despite its relatively simple form, Mathematica won't do this integral and I didn't find it in Gradshteyn and Rhyzik. Attempting to expand the denominator and make an infinite sum just turns into the infinite sum in the OP, but I'm curious if there is a form for the integral directly.

Comment: I think it can be done in terms of Jacobi theta functions and their integrals/derivatives.